# How do I cast this using Swift?

Tags: swift

I am working on an app where I'm trying to display `VNClassificationObservation` type onto the navigation bar title when I take a picture of an item. But I am encountering a problem of type casting. It shows the error:

> "Cast from 'VNClassificationObservation?' to unrelated type 'String'
>   always fails".

Please point me to the right direction.

```swift
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
    guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
                fatalError("Request failed.")
            }
    let firstResult = results.first as? String
    self.navigationItem.title = firstResult    
}
```

I expect the output to be printed out correctly onto the navigation title without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
let firstResult = results.first.identifier
```

Comment: @hidden_wizard https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work